# google home layout control works but no voice command

Tags: google-home

I am developing an integration with the goole assistant for my home automation, I use node red to handle api calls in the webhook and the flow is handling well the calls SYNC, QUERY and EXECUTE when using the graphical interface of the google home app.

however when I use the voice command I receive the EXECUTE request and the lamp turn on, but I do not receive the QUERY request which causes google home to say that the service is not available.

I don't understand what is going wrong because when I use the graphical interface of google home I get EXECUTE and then QUERY normally. What could be wrong?